# JavaScript: Promise chaining in foreach loop

Tags: javascript, loops, typescript, promise

I'm new to javascript promises and am having difficulty using them with a collection of elements.  Within the collection, I perform an operation which returns a promise. Once the entire operation (including all the Promises in the collection) has completed, I need to perform another set of operations. The promises within the collection need to go in sequence.

I have tried the following approach:

```
public cleanup(onCleanupComplete: any): void {
        if (this._app == null) return; //this._app comes out of an external API

       // Below line of code won't compile, it is just for illustration. 
       // I'm trying to show that I need a promise in return from method
        this.removeConference(0).then(() => {
              // Do additional clean up operation and call onCleanupComplete
                onCleanupComplete(true, null);                
        });

    }

    private removeConference(i : number) {
        if (this._app.conversationsManager.conversations == null 
           || i === this.conversationLength)
            return; // this.conversationLength equals initial 
                    // number of elements in collection 
                    // How do I return a promise here?

        var conversation = this._app.conversationsManager.conversations(0);
                console.log("app.cleanup.leave", `Leaving conversation ${conversation}`);
        conversation.leave().then(() => {
                console.log("app.cleanup.leave", `Conversation ${conversation} left successfully`);
            this.app.conversationsManager.conversations.remove(conversation);
 _           this.removeConference(i);
        });
    }
```

What should I return from removeConference once all the `conversations` in collection are removed?

Comment: Where is the forEAch loop or am I blind

Comment: Datsik: Will edit my question.

Comment: Hi Datsik, I have updated the question. I hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

So this is something that nabbed me early on in understanding promises. You need to get ALL of your code away from the practice of passing in a callback, and then simply using the promise to call that. Instead, to keep the continuous nature of promises, you want to just *return* promises to the calling function, unless your function is the one that should decide what to do afterward. So, your code should look something like this.

```
public cleanup(onCleanupComplete: any):Promise<any> {
        if (this._app == null) return; //this._app comes out of an external API

       // Below line of code won't compile, it is just for illustration. 
       // I'm trying to show that I need a promise in return from method
       var promiseArray = [];
       for (var i = 0; i < this.conversationLength; i++) {
         promiseArray.push(removeConference(i));
       }
       return Promise.all(promiseArray);

    }

    private removeConference(i : number):Promise<any> {
        if (this._app.conversationsManager.conversations == null 
           || i === this.conversationLength)
            return Promise.resolve(true);

        var conversation = this._app.conversationsManager.conversations(0);
                console.log("app.cleanup.leave", `Leaving conversation ${conversation}`);
        return conversation.leave().then(() => {
                console.log("app.cleanup.leave", `Conversation ${conversation} left successfully`);
            this.app.conversationsManager.conversations.remove(conversation);
            this.removeConference(i);
        });
    }
```

I'm not 100% sure this compiles correctly, but hopefully it helps conceptually. `Promise.all` is really the key function here - it takes an array of promises, and creates a matching "control promise" that only resolves when all of them have.